# Better way to get the value out of a 1-length dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to parse a dictionary that has a variable key name incoming from an outside program.

```
d = {"Something": {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}}
```

or

```
d = {"ADifferentName": {"one": 11, "two": 22, "three": 33}}
```

I want to reference the value under `Something` or `ADifferentName` in a way that is better than this:

```
value = d[list(d.keys())[0]]
```

I did some research and didn't find anything better than `iter()` and 2 lines of code. Is there not some Python built-in that says "just give me the first key I don't care what it's called"?

Comment: Do you want the key, or the value? `key, = d`, `value, = d.values()`? Note that these will be unhappy for input that doesn't have exactly one key, which may or may not be helpful for you.

Comment: From the edit it seems that the crucial part is actually to get the *value* from the *outer dictionary*, currently `d[list(d.keys())[0]]`. Iterating over that inner dictionary's keys is then trivial (and therefore not actually relevant here). I've edited accordingly. *"Is there not some Python built-in that says "just give me the first key I don't care what it's called"?"* - dictionaries aren't semantically ordered data structures, they don't have a "first key".

Comment: *"just give me the first key I don't care what it's called"* — How about `key = next(iter(d))`?

Comment: @L3viathan that also works, thank you

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for your edits, you're correct in that I want the value under the key names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite the same as your code, but with no keys (it works only wth 1-length dictionary):

```
list(d.values())[0]
```

And for the keys:

```
list(d.values())[0].keys()
```

Comment: *"it works only wth 1-length dictionary"* - that's not true, you can get the 0th value from any dictionary with more than 0 keys.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include @L3viathan's comment? `next(iter(d))` also works in one line

Comment: @Locane why don't you ask them to post a separate answer?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's fine too; happy to upvote a separate answer - I didn't ask because IME people don't read all the answers on SO, they just take the one that's green-checked

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by [L3viathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016216/l3viathan) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63989678/better-way-to-get-the-value-out-of-a-1-length-dictionary/63989835?noredirect=1#comment113153729_63989678), you can use `iter` and `next` to access the first key or value:

```
>>> d = {"Something": {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}}
>>> next(iter(d))
'Something'
>>> next(iter(d.values()))
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

This is more efficient than building a list then indexing into it, although that isn't likely to be important for small dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the dictionary will contain exactly one key-value pair, you can just use assignment (note the comma in the [target list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)) to extract the key or the value:

```
>>> d = {"Something": {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}}
>>> key, = d
>>> key
'Something'
>>> value, = d.values()
>>> value
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

This will throw a `ValueError` if the number of keys is anything other than one:

```
>>> key, = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```